# View JSON feed Swift 3.0

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I am trying to view my php result in an IOS app.
The code is the following:

```
 func get()
    {
        //let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.w3schools.com/js/customers_mysql.php")
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.helpmewastetime.com/service.php")
        let data = NSData(contentsOf: url! as URL)

        values = try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! NSArray


        var array = [""]
        array = (values.value(forKey: "Name") as? [String])!
        lb_Value.text = array[0]


    }
```

The code is working fine for the w3schools link, however it crashes when I use my link (hosted on go daddy)
If you open the links from a web browser, we get the intended result.

This is the error received:

```
2016-11-30 16:44:24.977781 Fun iOS App[2590:112849] [] __nw_connection_get_connected_socket_block_invoke 2 Connection has no connected handler
2016-11-30 16:44:24.979616 Fun iOS App[2590:112846] PAC stream failed with
2016-11-30 16:44:24.981519 Fun iOS App[2590:112849] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork: 2
2016-11-30 16:44:26.145018 Fun iOS App[2590:112849] [] nw_endpoint_handler_add_write_request [1.1.1 107.180.54.250:80 failed socket-flow (satisfied)] cannot accept write requests
2016-11-30 16:44:26.145764 Fun iOS App[2590:112847] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [22] Invalid argument
2016-11-30 16:44:26.150620 Fun iOS App[2590:112846] [] nw_proxy_resolver_create_parsed_array PAC evaluation error: kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork: 2
fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-800.0.58.6/src/swift/stdlib/public/core/ErrorType.swift, line 178
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: http://www.helpmewastetime.com/service.php points to an [HTML page](https://www.evernote.com/l/AOyy9a1kG7xDtbawSnrbB41nOVEqpXWDYnc), not to a JSON response...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Eric Aya mentioned in his comment. The issue is that your PHP service spits out the JSON data into an HTML page.

When I view source of your page I get the following:

```
<html>
[{"ID":"1","Name":"Peter"},{"ID":"2","Name":"James"}]
</html>
```

The page source of the w3schools url is simply JSON. In your PHP service, output your data in JSON and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks Todd! Works fine now